# twitter bootstrap model event "shown" called twice using jquery on event handler

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I load the Twitter Bootstrap Model (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) using:

```
$("#multiple_choice_question").modal();
```

I then call jQuery's .on() even handler to perform some more actions once the Model has fully loaded but the .on() function seems to be called twice?

For example If I do this, I get two random numbers:

```
$("#multiple_choice_question").on("shown",function() {
    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)); 
});
```

How can I stop this?

Comment: Fixed! $("#multiple_choice_question").unbind("shown");

Comment: Can you show where you call `modal()` : on user action, on ready ? FYI, this `modal()` doesn't need to be called if your trigger has a `data-toggle="modal"`. Can you try to reproduce the bug in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/3KVXA/) for example ?

Comment: Unbind doesn't worker for me, registering the event with `.one('shown')` instead of `.on('shown')` fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**@simo**'s answer of registering the event with `.one('shown')` worked for me. From the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/one/), use `.one()` to "Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type."